# PL/SQL update statement error

Tags: plsql

```
--Student(id, company)  Table schema

create or replace procedure student_update(
  v_company IN VARCHAR2(10),
  v_id IN NUMBER
)
IS
BEGIN
  update student set company=v_company where  id=v_id;
  commit;
END student_update;
/
```

Error: Encountered the symbol '(' where expecting one of the following

Answer (score 0):

Need to change the dataType of the parameters

```
create or replace procedure student_update(
   v_company IN student.company%TYPE,
   v_id IN student.id%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN
  update student set company=v_company where id=v_id;
END;
/
```

This works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot give a length to you parameters. If you really need to limit v_company to 10, you can do a length check inside the procedure.

You might also consider looking into using Native Dynamic SQL. You're at risk running code straight from inputs.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE student_update
(
   v_company IN VARCHAR2
  ,v_id      IN NUMBER
) IS
BEGIN
   IF LENGTH(v_company) > 10 THEN
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'Company must be 10 Char or less.');
   END IF;

   UPDATE student SET company = v_company WHERE ID = v_id;

   COMMIT;
END student_update;
/
```